# strange blank page on google chrome

Tags: java, jsf, google-chrome, richfaces

I've spent a few hours to find out the cause of this blank page:

[page removed for security reasons]

It's hard to understand why all the source code appears ok but the page is blank...

Please note that in FF/IE it's working ok...

Does anybody see the problem?

**Solved**: The problem was the js plugin which loaded the text containing a wrong closed tag for link.

old:

```
<a/>
```

new:):

```
</a>
```

Yes....i agree...most of the errors come from small things.

Answer (score 0):

in your main div
style="display:none;"

you should remove it there

Comment: That's not the problem. Some javascript is supposed to modify this (possibly to make it fade in or something), but isn't firing on Chrome. Check in another browser and you'll see that it works.

Comment: http://www.blackcan.com/test/test1.html does show content with display none removed